# Maximize a ReportViewer in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I have a windows forms application with VS 2019, I have a form and inside I added a report viewer. The report works fine but I want to show it maximized when I open the form, so I put WindowState = Maximized in the form but the ReportViewer doesn't move. If I resize and maximize the form manually, then it happens. For the ReportViewer I put Dock = Fill and ZoomMode = FullPage.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Forcing the report to refresh _on size change_ (.RefreshReport();) might work.

Comment: Looking at the `Remarks` section of the `MaximizeBox` property on the Control (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.maximizebox?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#remarks) and as @dr.null suggest, the `Resize` event might be useful to look into, if you enable the `MaximizeBox` on the Form, when you click the Maximize button, does that work and resize the form?

Comment: Thank you so much guys!, I will test it right away

Comment: Actually I set the form to maximize by default but the resize does not happens

Comment: I was able to handle it on the SizeChanged of the form, thank you